# Solving a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have three ordinary differential equations, with 3 dependent variables, $n_i$, $n_e$ and $\phi$, as follows:

$$\nabla (-\frac{dn_i}{dx}-k_1n_i\frac{d\phi}{dx})=0$$

$$\nabla (-\frac{dn_e}{dx}+n_e\frac{d\phi}{dx})=0$$

$$\nabla (\frac{d\phi}{dx})+k_2(n_e-n_1)=0$$

being evaluated between $x=r_1$ and $x=r_2$, with $k_1$ and $k_2$ being known constants.

In the above $\nabla(-)=\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-)\right]$. So, for example, the first equation expands to:

$$-\left(\frac{d^2n_i}{dx^2}+\frac1x\frac{dn_i}{dx}+k_1\frac{dn_i}{dx}\frac{d\phi}{dx}+k_1n_i\frac{d^2\phi}{dx}+\frac{2k_1n_i}{x}\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)=0$$

I have the following boundary conditions: $n_{i,e}(x=r_1)=0$, $n_{i,e}(x=r_2)=1$, $\phi(r_2)=0$.

I'm attempting to use modelling software in order to solve this system, as part of a project I'm working on. I assumed I would be given $\phi(r_1)$, but I won't. My question is quite ill-defined, and apologies if this isn't quite the right place, or if I haven't given enough information. I would like to know just how much information can be gathered about the dependent variables, and specifically $\phi$. I come from a pure math background, and have little-to-no experience in solving differential equations, bar one module in my undergraduate degree quite a while ago.

I can't imagine this system would be solvable without the help of a computer, however if someone could explain whether or not the system is solvable given those boundary conditions, or if the unattainable sixth condition, $\phi(r_1)$, is necessary. Could anyone recommend any good resources that deals with the methodology involved in solving such a system, that would outline the general steps? This way, if my hunch is correct that a full solution isn't possible without that condition, I can at least get an idea of how far I can get with just the above.

Any help given would be much appreciated, I realise I'm asking quite a lot here. Also if I can give any more information, please tell me. Thanks.